# Two questions about Looper's mysterious villain

Tags: looper

Two questions about about Cid.

1. If he knows that old Joe is the one who kills his mom, why send him back to set things in motion?
2. Why use loopers at all in this case? The opening monologue says "[i]t’s nearly impossible to dispose of a body in the future. I’m told. Tagging techniques, whatnot.", but if he's in control of the "five major syndicates" and he did it alone, and if Old Joe's wife could be shot seemingly without consequence, what's the barrier here?

Comment: Multiple questions asked in a single post are generally frowned upon and will likely be closed. You can ask two questions for each of your items.

Comment: @A.Steer they're related, and it drew an answer.

Comment: I'll happily split my answers if the question is split. As it is, if someone finds a better answer for, say, why Cid sends Loopers back, we'd be stuck with two answers which are both good, but you can only accept one.

Answer (score 4):

[Rian Johnson did an interview](https://www.slashfilm.com/523142/ten-mysteries-in-looper-explained-by-director-rian-johnson/?utm_campaign=clip) where he partially explained that first plot point:

> **The film surmises Old Joe killing Sarah eventually made Cid become the Rainmaker. But Old Joe can't become Old Joe without first being killed and letting Young Joe grow up to meet his wife. In that timeline though, Cid would grow up normal because Sarah wasn't killed by Joe. How does that all work? How does the Rainmaker exist in a timeline where Old Joe didn't kill his mom?**
>
> Unfortunately, this is the chicken and the egg explanation. There is no answer. One thing is dependent on the other but couldn't have happened if the other didn't. I'll let Johnson take the lead here.
>
> "That's the Terminator question. If it's important to you to really justify that beyond 'It makes sense in a story type way,' you'll have to get into multiple time lines existing in neverending loops of logic. You can shoehorn it into making sense," he said. "For me it's a trope of time travel movies and there's a slight amount of magic logic that you have to apply in order for a story like this to make sense."
>
> He does, however, point to the mention of the Rainmaker having a fake jaw in the future, then being shot in the present, as one particular connection. "That specific thing must have already happened, but he's still in the timeline where that has yet to happen. Although, in my mind, what happens is cause his memory is shifting to accommodate, that's one of the things that's changed in his memory." I guess we'll never know for sure but my guess is that this loop has happened lots and times, we're just seeing the final one.

....

> **Knowing a looper killed his mother, is the Rainmaker closing all these loops for revenge?**
>
> "Or is he doing it because he's come to power and he's wiping everything out? It's a good question." says Johnson, suggesting there's really no answer.

And the second one:

> **How does murder work in the future? Why can't the mobsters kill there and what happens when Joe's wife is killed?**
>
> The film mentions briefly mentions that, in the future, tracking technology stops murders from happening. But we explicitly see Joe's wife murdered in the future. Johnson said this was one of several things he worked out in his head but didn't put in the movie because it felt superfluous to the story. He instead explained it to us.
>
> "Everybody in the movie has this nano technology tracking in their body and whenever there's a death, a location tag is sent to the authorities from this tracking material. So they can't kill people in the future. But if they send them back, that is not triggered." He continues, "The material is powered off the body's heat and it has a two year life after the person dies." As for the wife, that was a big mistake made by the mobsters and the reason we see the shot of the village burning is that's their half-assed attempt to cover it up.